# Doctrine select in() as boolean

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm trying to use doctrine ORM querybuilder to do select using the IN function as a NULL/1 value

I did this in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT status IN ('APPROVED','REVIEW') as haveAccess
  FROM media WHERE group_id = 1;
```

The result would be this:

```
+------------+
| haveAccess |
+------------+
|       NULL |
|          1 |
+------------+
```

Now using querybuilder, I can't get it to work.  I tried:

```
$qb->addSelect($qb->expr()->in('m.status',$arrayOfStatus));

$qb->addSelect($qb->expr()->in('m.status',$arrayOfStatus). " as haveAccess");

$implodedArray = implode(",",$arrayOfStatus);
$qb->addSelect("m.status IN ($implodedArray) as haveAccess");
```

The error I got is

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 28 near '('APPROVED','REVIEW')': Error: Class '(' is not defined.
```

I tried echoing out what the expr()->in() gives me:

```
echo $qb->expr()->in('m.status',$arrayOfStatus);
//m.status IN('APPROVED','REVIEW')
```

and the output seems semantically correct.  Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why can't you just use an easier SQL statement? `SELECT status AS haveAccess FROM media WHERE status IN ('APPROVED','REVIEW') AND group_id = 1;` or am I missing something?

Comment: 1. My whole project is using query builder, I don't want to have one query standing out there using native SQL.

Comment: 2. I want to select the IN as a boolean, not where the IN.  The reason being is that I want all the medias returned regardless of status, but I want to have a field I can pivot off of to decide if the user has access or not.  (Think returning 404 vs 401)